# PHP Respond now, process later

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently trying to import **a huge number** of students from an external place. I'm doing this in a Controller exposing a route. I receive an error message `Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. I want to avoid setting `set_time_limit(0)`. Is there another way to avoid that error and continue the process? If I build a command, everything works good, since the time limit is set to 0. I also tried to run a command from the controller, but that leads to same error. I need to do it from a controller, that is why I'm still looking for a solution.

Also, is there a way to return a Response and still have the process to run in the background?

Comment: i recommand to you docs about RabbitMQ and Component Process included into Symfony 2. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, depending on how often the data you return should be updated, and how long it actually takes to process it.

First, if the data can be updated on a daily or a weekly basis, you could make your command save its output some place accessible to the web app, and add a cron job to generate the output every once in a while. Next, just make sure the result is accessible to the user.

Second option is a bit more harder to implement but more flexible as well. You can utilise RabbitMQ and [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle) or similar queue server so that when a user requests the data, you only submit a message into the queue, and then the message is received by a worker that somehow updates the web application data (runs your command),  denoting that the process has been completed and caching the result somehow. This way, you'd get fresh results right away, but the load would be not as predictable (that's why you should consider caching).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamedResponse` which allows you to stream the Response back to the client using a callback.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    var_dump('Hello World');
    flush();
    sleep(2);
    var_dump('Hello World');
    flush();
});
$response->send();
```

See more info here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response

Comment: Tried that. I still receive a `Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` message.

Comment: You still have to allow the script to run for longer, but with this method at least you can keep the user posted on the progress of the process

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to change the default value of 30 seconds. And also, I don;t need to inform the user about the progress. I just want the command to run in background without him to know.

Comment: Ok, then take a look at the other answer, just wanted to suggest something which is easier to implement

Comment: what we do is: we just queue commands on amazon sqs, and have several workers picking up and running those commands (technically sort of what rabbit does)